# Configurable product- greyed out variation/associated product

Tags: configurable-product, associated-products

I have a configurable product and would like to add a variation/associated product to it however it's greyed out and won't let me select it!

Why is this so?

Best,

Michelle

Comment: Can you add more information to your question? What version of Magento? Has the product just been added, or was it already setup with existing simple products? Are you in the admin screen, and are you looking in the "Configurations" tab, or are you trying to use the "Customizable Options" tab?

Comment: Hiya, I'm currently using Magento 2 and i'm talking about the admin screen in backend. I created a product that is a configurable product. When you click to edit the configurable product you can click on 'configurations' to add different variations to it... i.e. different colours. However when I try to add the products manually the variation I had only created is greyed out and not selectable.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about website frontend then it means your product's variation/simple product is out of stock.

Please add quantity to simple product and run `php bin/magetno indexer:reindex` command and reload frontend..now check..

Comment: Hiya, I'm currently using Magento 2 and i'm talking about the admin screen in backend. I created a product that is a configurable product. When you click to edit the configurable product you can click on 'configurations' to add different variations to it... i.e. different colours. However when I try to add the products manually the variation I had only created is greyed out and not selectable.

Comment: it means same variation's product is already assigned to your configurable product.